# Extending the Android Text-To-Speech(TTS) language pack

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have been defining a new language for the Espeak text-to-speech (TTS) using espeak(desktop application).
I have successfully defined the language but have been unable to find a way to export the language files to android TTS engine (such as PICO TTS).
I want to integrate the new language the existing language pack in android. 
Can anyone help me or direct me in an appropriate direction !

---

I'm currently trying to export a new language from espeak to Android too but I'm stuck. 
 Please offer me any tips on the same.
Thanks !

Comment: Are you using the eSpeak for Android port? It's available on the Play Store. Once that's installed, you can just copy/paste your data files into the existing espeak-data directory on your SD card.