# Android TTS with Korean Language

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

It seems that the android TTS classes found in the sdk does not support the korean language, what options do I have for doing text to speech with Android using Korean? For example are there some java libraries that will work? I have searched and have not found a solution so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.ispeech.org/developers) is a great library to work with. I am using it for English TTS and speech is very natural and realistic. They also have Korean language.

The only handicap is having a little dialog box appearing on the screen for a very short time when the speech is playing but it is required for ensuring their copyrights. There is an option of disabling that by paying them I guess. If you do not mind this, it is very convenient to use.

Comment: From reading the documentation of ispeech you need an ongoing connection to the internet. How does this affect the behaviour of your app? And how have you designed your app to compensate from poor or no network connection?

Comment: @JulianHarty, My app requires network connection so that is not a problem. In your case, you might need to go for an offline solution, which stores the recognition database offline and increases your memory requirements.

Comment: Erol, thank you for your suggestion. We don't need audio recognition, just the ability to do text-to-speech. At the moment we're planning to experiment with adding raw resources containing the audio segments for languages such as Vietnamese where Android doesn't have the language available in TTS, for others we'll use the svox language or the general ones provided with Android.

Comment: @JulianHarty Is there anyway you can share your progress and approach to solve this problem in offline scenarios. I am looking to implement or find a support for major languages in my region.

Comment: @SSR Yes, Happy to do so. Would you be interested in co-creating small Android project(s) where we experiment? I envisage several scenarios, including: 1) How to get 'this app' to speak in a particular language (where audio snippets are provided as resources with the app (or on SD Card in known locations) 2) creating a TTS Voice for a particular language, similar to those sold on Google Play. I'm julianharty@gmail.com if you'd like to discuss by email, etc.

Comment: @SSR the following question might also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161743/extending-the-android-text-to-speechtts-language-pack?rq=1